# React typescript optional parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript

New to react/typescript. I am trying to create a function with a typscripted param.

example:

```
export function get_prod(category: string) { ...}
```

The problem is I have 2 product scenarios. One can have an optional category, the other type requires a category to only load products from that category but otherwise the function is almost identical.

I wanted to do something like this:

```
if category = 'ebook' {
    arg = 'category: string'
} else
    arg = 'category?: string'
}

export function get_prod(arg) { ...}
```

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: How are you planning on selecting the product without a title? Surely `title?: string` + whatever other parameters you already need to select the products without a title would work?

Comment: That was just a simplistic example, the code is a lot more complex but I wanted to keep the example simple albeit in hindsight probably a bad example. let me update it.

Comment: u'll probably need generics

`export function wrap<T extends string>(category: T){
  return function get_prod(category: T extends 'ebook'?string:(string | void)){
    // something like this
  };
}`

it does depend on the outer construct a bit tho (and in general it only works if you call it with a constant where the string is typed as "ebook")

Answer (score 0):

You could use [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) to define custom types and accept their union as a parameter (basically, either one). For example:

```
type Book = { category: string };
type Other = { id: number, category?: string };

const getProduct = (product: Book | Other) => {
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use overloads like this:

```
type TProduct = {
    productName: string
    id: number
};

function getProduct(category: 'ebook'): TProduct
function getProduct(id: number, category?: string): TProduct
function getProduct(category?: any, id: any): TProduct {
    return { productName: 'productName', id: 123 };
}

const productA = getProduct(123);
const productB = getProduct(123, 'dasdsa');
const productC = getProduct('ebook');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type Params = {category: 'ebook'} | {category?: string; otherParam: unknown};
export function get_prod(arg: Params) { ...}
```